# Erro no Script com PHP 7.1

Tags: php, syntax-error, php-7.1

Estou com um problema em um módulo que antes funcionava corretamente na versão 5.6 do PHP.

Após atualizar o PHP do servidor para 7.1 deixou de funcionar, devido a algumas funções que antes estavam presentes no PHP 5.6 e deixaram de existir a partir da versão 7.1.

Ao tentar rodar o módulo, me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Erro no Comando do Módulo
mysql_data_seek is not supported
```

Segue trecho do código com a função `mysql_data_seek`, onde ocorre o erro:

```
  function _mysql_result($result, $iRow, $field = 0)
{
    if(!mysql_data_seek($result, $iRow))
        return false;
    if(!($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
        return false;
    if(!array_key_exists($field, $row))
        return false;
    return $row[$field];
}
```

De acordo com o PHP necessito alterar para MySQLi, mas meu conhecimento é muito limitado nesta questão.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/

Comment: Você simplesmente entendendo o que cada comando faz, verifica qual é "relativo" do `mysqli`, e os substitui. As vezes mudam-se a ordem das propriedades, as vezes ficam até mais simples e enxutos. Você consegue! É só ir percorrendo e entendendo cada trecho do seu código.